# Infinite loop between main program and thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
namespace MP3_speler.Threading
{
public class thread : MainWindow
{
    public thread() 
    {
        StartThreading();          
    }

    public void StartThreading() 
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WorkThreadFunction));
        thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
        thread.Start();            
    }

    public void WorkThreadFunction()
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateMyDelegatedelegate UpdateMyDelegate = new UpdateMyDelegatedelegate(UpdateMyDelegateLabel);
            timelabel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, UpdateMyDelegate, (Convert.ToInt32(mp3FileReader.Position / 10000)));
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        catch 
        {

        }
    }

    private void UpdateMyDelegateLabel(int i)
    {
        double timeseconds = (double)mp3FileReader.Position / (double)176000;

        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeseconds);

        string answer = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}",
                        t.Hours,
                        t.Minutes,
                        t.Seconds
                        );

        timelabel.Content = answer;


        if (waveOut.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Paused) Slider2.Value = mp3FileReader.Position;

    }
}
}
```

Code Mainprogram:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public IWavePlayer waveOut;
    public Mp3FileReader mp3FileReader;
    public delegate void UpdateMyDelegatedelegate(int i);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Create a thread
        thread thread = new thread();
        //Setting up notifyicon
        notifyCenter notify = new notifyCenter(this);
        //giving values to bars
        Slider1.Value = 5;
        volumelabel.Content = 50;
    }
```

This code generates an infinite loop and goes back to Initializecomponent all the time.
Maybe the problem is that I made the Thread class inherit the MainWindow but would like to know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the fact that `thread` derives from `MainWindow` is causing the infinite loop.

In `MainWindow`'s constructor, it creates a new `thread` object. However, because `thread` derives from `MainWindow`, it then re-invokes `MainWindow`'s constructor, when creates a `thread`, repeat ad infinitum.

Remember that when deriving, your constructor will always invoke the base class default constructor unless you explicitly instruct to use a different one.

As an aside, there are no use cases I can think of for ever deriving from `MainWindow` and this certainly isn't one. You will need to rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to make sure!

Comment: You could try changing `public class thread : MainWindow` to `public partial class MainWindow : Window`, get rid of the `thread()` constructor and put the call to `StartThreading();` in your MainWindow constructor.  Not sure how that will work with the `namespace MP3_speler.Threading' namespace though.

Comment: @MikeofSST, He's obviously in the same namespace, so that part is ok. I don't see a lot of benefit to doing so (besides splitting up the code files (is that really a good thing?)) but it would work.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Thanks for the confirmation.  I can't see the benefit either (I'd put it in the ViewModel myself, as I use a no-code-behind View in my applications).  It just seemed like a quick fix for the isa/hasa problem.  :-)